# How to simplify this trigonometric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am not sure how to further simplify this expression:
$$\sec^2(\arcsin(y/r)) \times \frac{\frac{1}{r}}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{y}{r})^2}} \times \frac{r}{1000}$$

How should I further simplify the $\sec^2(\arcsin(y/r))$?
The simplified version looks like this:
$$\left(\frac r{10\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}\right)^3$$

Comment: please avoid referring to external sources. also show your work, otherwise you may not be able benefit from the community here. I also edited your question a bit, hope that helps :-)

Comment: $\arcsin(x)=\arccos(\sqrt{1-x^2})$

Comment: Try with the relations: $x=r\cos \phi$, $y=r\sin \phi$, $\tan\phi=y/x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sec^2(\arcsin(\frac{y}{r})),\;\frac{1}{\cos^2(\arcsin(\frac{y}{r}))}$
Trig identity: $\cos^2a=1-\sin^2a$. Replace $a$ with $\arcsin(a)$: $\cos^2(\arcsin(a))=1-a^2$
$\frac{1}{1-\frac{y^2}{r^2}}; \;\frac{r^2}{r^2-y^2}$, where $r\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from: $$\sec^2\left(\arcsin\left(\frac yr\right)\right) \times \frac{\frac{1}{r}}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{y}{r})^2}} \times \frac{r}{1000}.\tag 1$$

We know that $$\sec \left(\arcsin \left(x\right)\right)=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2}\implies \sec^2 \left(\arcsin \left(x\right)\right)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ then rewrite the $(1)$ like as:

$$\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac yr\right)^2}\times  \frac{\frac{1}{r}}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{y}{r})^2}} \times \frac{r}{1000} \tag 2$$

$$\frac{r^2}{r^2-y^2}\times \frac{\frac{1}{\not r}}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{y}{r})^2}}\times \frac{\not r}{1000}=\frac{r^2}{r^2-y^2}\times \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}\times \frac{1}{10^3}=\left(\frac{r}{10\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}\right)^3$$